# Harry stands up, but wasn't he already standing up?

Tags: harry-potter

> 'Well, we've got to try, haven't we?' said Harry. He stood up and pressed his own ear against the door.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban: Chapter 21</sup></sub>

Harry and Hermione are in a broom cupboard and the chapter once mentions that Hermione sat down on an upturned bucket; But it doesn't mention that about Harry. **If he was standing the whole time, how could he have stood up?**

Did I not understand this properly?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you rephrase this to make it a little clearer what you're asking though? For example, if the question is _"What do you think?"_, it could do with being rephrased to be a bit more specific, i.e. _"What do you think about [blank]?"_

Comment: Also, if the narration states that Harry "stood up", it logically follows that he _must not_ have been standing up immediately before that, since you cannot stand up if you are already standing. The absence of an earlier statement that he sat down doesn't prove he never did; it just means the reader wasn't _told_ he did (if he did).

Comment: Welcome Penz. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways, enjoy Sci-Fi and Fantasy.

Answer (score 5):

We, the reader, aren't told what Harry's doing in the cupboard for those few minutes, but we can make a few [inferences from context](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-inference.html).

Given that he "stood up", it follows logically that he wasn't standing before (e.g. he must be seated, crouching or recumbent). Certainly the author would have mentioned if he was lying on his back or front(!), so seated is the most obvious choice.

Given that Hermione (the smart one) makes herself a *proper* seat, it's likely that Harry (the dumb one) was just sitting on the floor where Hermione had pushed him.

> ‘In here!’ Hermione seized Harry’s arm and dragged him across the hall
> to the door of a broom cupboard; she opened it, **pushed him inside
> amongst the buckets and mops, followed him in, then slammed the door
> behind them.**